# Add link to site front page from network profile Accounts tab

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

When I'm browsing Stack Exchange in my spare time, I find [the network profile accounts tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/35227/kevin-reid?tab=accounts) to be a handy starting point to bookmark; it basically lists the sites by my participation level (as measured by reputation) and so automatically contains what I want to get access to, and also provides a status update — it's doing a good job of being *Your Stack Exchange Home Page*.

It would be even better at this job if the list of sites included a link to the front page of each site, whereas it currently only has a link to my profile page for each site. Of course, it's only one additional click as it is.

(See also [my other feature request for this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163270/add-mobile-version-of-network-profile-page), which would ideally be available together with this but is logically separate.)