# Add mobile version of network profile page

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, network-profile

When I'm browsing Stack Exchange in my spare time from my phone, I find [the network profile accounts tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/35227/kevin-reid?tab=accounts) to be a handy starting point to bookmark; it basically lists the sites by my participation level (as measured by reputation) and so automatically contains what I want to get access to, and also provides a status update — it's doing a good job of being *Your Stack Exchange Home Page*.

However, it would be nice if there were a ‘mobile’ formatting of this page; specifically so as to provide the existing mobile-version design of the notification dropdown, which is the part least convenient to use from a phone.

(See also [my other feature request for this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163267/add-link-to-site-front-page-from-network-profile-accounts-tab), which would ideally be available together with this but is logically separate.)